# Angularjs not showing statusText and code in .catch()

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-headers

I'm still in trouble with **AngularJS 1.5.3**.

I'm trying to do some logic with the *401 Unauthorized* error in my `$http` requests.

Here the code.

```
...
var req = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/news',
  method: 'GET'
};
$http(req)
.then(successHandler)
.catch(function(message) {
  console.log(message);
  if(message.status === "401") {
       // logic here
  }
});
...
```

After running this little piece of code without auth token I got:

```
Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

The browser know is 401, and display it in an error before the `console.log`.

[image]

What the heck is happening?

Comment: You need to provide additional data. A status of `-1` is usually the result of a timeout or a canceled query. Are you performing a CORS request? What does the request look like?

Comment: yep, probably is a CORS problem. I'm using 'slim framework' as backend. The request is simple: an URL and the GET method. The authorization header is left blank by purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the [documentation of angular's $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [angular's $q (angular promising)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Try using `.then()`-method, it expects two parameters, the first one is the callback in case of a http-success, the second in case of http-error. So you can write something like:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/news').then(
  function(resp) {
    //whatever happens when everything is fine
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(message);
    if(error === "401") {
      // logic here
    }
  }
);
```

Furthermore `$http.get()` is a shorthand to your `method: 'GET'` and `promise.catch(errorCallback)` is a shorthand for `promise.then(null, errorCallback)`

Best regards.

Comment: Already tried, the error still there! :) Thank you.

Comment: Neither `.then()` nor `.catch()` are members of `$http`. Instead calling `$http(...)` returns a promise which has the member functions `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Comment: updated my answer, thank you.